# Validate PropTypes, with array and single children side by side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

## Validate children

To validate the prop `children`, I use the following definition:

```
children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element),
    PropTypes.element,
  ]),
```

Which is valid for most situations:

```
// PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element)
<Component>
 {[
  <Childcomponent />,
  <Childcomponent />,
 ]}
</Component>

// PropTypes.element
<Component>
  <Childcomponent />
</Component>
```

But it seems impossible to validate a structure with mixed types:

```
<Component>
 {[
  <Childcomponent />,
  <Childcomponent />,
 ]}
 <Childcomponent />
</Component>

// Failed propType: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Component`.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.props.children` can be either a single element or an array of elements. You can do your validation like this:

```
const elementOrArrayOfElementPropType = PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element),
  PropTypes.element,
]);

...

propTypes: {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.arrayOf(elementOrArrayOfElementPropType),
    elementOrArrayOfElementPropType,
  ]),
}
```

You basically had to go one level deeper, as you can have an array of arrays of components, just an array of components or just a component.

Comment: Eventually I used `children: PropTypes.node`, but your solution works, too!

Comment: It's maddening that this is the least verbose it gets without just using `PropTypes.node`, which allows damn near everything. How this could not be covered in either PropTypes or Airbnb's PropTypes, I truly cannot comprehend.